# java regex parse

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Thanks for checking out my question.

Here the user enter the string in the format: "xD xS xP xH". The program takes the string, splits it on the space bar, then uses regex to parse the string. There is an issue with my "final string regex" and I am not sure where.

```
final String regex = "([0-9]+)[D|d]| ([0-9]+)[S|s]| ([0-9]+)[P|p]| ([0-9]+)[H|h]";
```

Lastly, the loop prints out only the value for D so I suspect it reaches an error moving to match S or s.

```
public class parseStack
{
   public parseStack()
   {
      System.out.print('\u000c');
      String CurrencyFormat = "xD xS xP xH";
      System.out.println("Please enter currency in the following format: \""+CurrencyFormat+"\" where x is any integer");

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       String currencyIn = scan.nextLine();
       currencyFinal = currencyIn.toUpperCase();
       System.out.println("This is the currency you entered: "+currencyFinal);

       String[] tokens = currencyFinal.split(" ");
       final String input = tokens[0];
       final String regex = "([0-9]+)[D|d]| ([0-9]+)[S|s]| ([0-9]+)[P|p]| ([0-9]+)[H|h]";

       if (input.matches(regex) == false) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is malformed.");            
       }

        long[] values = Arrays.stream(input.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4").split(" "))
                .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
                .toArray();

      for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println("value of i: "+i+ "    |" +values[i]+ "|");
      }

    //pause to print
    System.out.println("Please press enter to continue . . . ");
    Scanner itScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nextIt = itScan.nextLine();    
 }
}
```

Comment: You split it, then you check the split segments against a regex which only matches with the string **before split**..

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem, and it might be better to provide a smaller sample of the code for quicker help

Comment: We don't debug your homework for you. You need to describe in as much detail as possible what your _specific_ issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should be `[\d]+[DdSsPpHh]`.

The problem you are having is you split the string into chunks, then you match chunks with a RegEx that matches the original string that you have split.

**HOWEVER** this answer only addresses a problem in your code. Your routine doesn't seem to cater your expectation. And your expectation is not clear at all.

**EDIT**

Added the multidigit requirement.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the grouping requirement, nor the multidigit requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be simplified somewhat.

```
"(?i)(\d+d) (\d+s) (\d+p) (\d+h)"
```

will do a case-insensitive match against multiple digits ( \d+ )

This can be further simplified into

```
"(?i)(\d+[dsph])"
```

which will iteratively match the various groups in your currency string.

Comment: I take that '\' ignores whatever is in front?  Also, what does '(?i)' do? i've never seen this before..

Comment: (?i) is java's way of saying "do a case insensitive pattern match".  \d is a regex escape code for digits [0-9] - see [POSIX extended regex syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your regex looks a bit to complex. You input format is *"xD xS xP xH"* also you are converting the input to uppercase `currencyIn = currencyIn.toUpperCase();` but this isn't the problem.

The problem is

```
String[] tokens = currencyIn.split(" ");
final String input = tokens[0];
```

You are splitting the input and only use the first part which would be *"xD"*

The fixed code would look like:

```
String currencyIn = scan.nextLine();
currencyIn = currencyIn.toUpperCase();
System.out.println("This is the currency you entered: "+currencyIn);

final String regex = "([0-9]+)D ([0-9]+)S ([0-9]+)P ([0-9]+)H";

if (!currencyIn.matches(regex)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is malformed.");
}

long[] values = Arrays.stream(currencyIn.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2 $3 $4").split(" "))
    .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
    .toArray();

for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("value of i: "+i+ "    |" +values[i]+ "|");
}
```